# how to upload file and store in folder in html java script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

how to upload file using html, get that file using java script and it will store in to local folder?
Another question is, we have upload file using html, that file name is display in browser, now is that file stored in the temp folder or somewhere?

Comment: not possible due to javascript security, if it's only a small file you might be able to do it with JS localstorage. Have a look into server side languages like php

Comment: If you're going to be sending something from client to server (such as a file) you're going to be needing ajax or use a html form. If you are server side and want to handle the file that was sent via ajax with js.. you're giong to need a js based server.. in that case you should look into node.js for example. Otherwise you need a php based server (apache2) to handle the file coming in.

Comment: is there any option in html5 file API?

Comment: html and javascript do run client-side. just think about how broken it would be if every client had write-access to your server, no matter what.

Comment: You need to understand the difference between client and server side. HTML is just a structure for webpages that the client sees. That's it. \